# npm install causing errors on Ubuntu 16 + node v6.x

Tags: node.js

I see the following errors when doing an npm install:

```
> fibers@1.0.13 install /home/deploy/xxx-server-v2/node_modules/fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js

`linux-x64-v8-5.0` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting

> bcrypt@0.8.7 install /home/deploy/xxx-server-v2/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/home/deploy/gym-patrol-server-v2/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
Killed
deploy@ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01:~/gym-patrol-server-v2$   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node
  COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
make: Leaving directory '/home/deploy/xxx-server-v2/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
```

When running 'npm install' on my local machine (mac), the above does not happen.
I did quiet a bit of research but don't know what is causing this to happen on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That "Killed" means the build process dies for some reason, likely due to lack of memory.

How much memory does the Ubuntu box (is it a VM? VPS? a toaster?) have?